# XNA BasicEffect, strange result on terrain with texture

Tags: c#, xna

At the moment i got a game project going where i will use the BasicEffect from XNA with defaultlighting on.

Simply put in class RenderLibManager

```
effect = new BasicEffect(device);
effect.EnableDefaultLighting = true;
```

This is working well on the normal 3D models, we got trees and a guy from the MSDN samples.
The problem is when i try to fetch the same basic effect from RenderLibManager to the world terrain file. I fetch it by doing

```
BasicEffect effect;
effect = RenderLibManager.effect;
```

And then i set the texture, cameraViewMatrix and cameraProjectionMatrix.

So when i start the game the terrain has a very dark blueish lighting. I don't really know why, but i was hoping someone could point me in the right direction.

Best regards, 
Kerrai

**EDIT**

[image: Ground lighting gone wrong]

Comment: "when i start the game the terrain has a very dark blueish lighting". Does this remain throughout the game?

Comment: Could you share the project for me?

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot?

Comment: **Edit** Added screenshot
And its the same lighting through out the playtime. 
Sharing my project isn't that simple as it contains a lot of unimportant code.

Comment: This might be caused by every thing xD. I saw so much awesome errors in others solutions like "order of operations" and so on. If you can make new project with important code that contains this error I will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually found the error on my own. After a very long investigation i had forgotten to generate the normals of the terrain, or even set them in the vertex buffer.

Thank you all for looking into the answer at least